# How do I take input from a user that includes a string and integer separated by white space?

Tags: c, input, syntax, scanf

How do I take input from a user that includes a string and integer separated by white space?

The user only enters in the following form:

```
string1 999 1001
```

where string1 can be any string not exceeding length 100
and integer that follows it can be any integer between 1 and 10^9 and the number of integers that follow the string can be 1 or 2

Like I can have

```
Ok see my code, but is basically useless. 
My problem is that the user enters inputs in following form

string1 
string2 100
string3 100 200
```

In first, only string is entered and no integer follows it
in 2nd, string and one integer follows it
in 3rd, two integers follow it

Requirement: I want to save the string to a variable "input" and the integers to a variable "num1", "num2" because I need to perform later on these.

How can I do this in C?
 I have been struggling on this since days please help

my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p, q;
    char input[100];

    printf("\nEnter:\n");
    scanf("%s %d %d", input, &p, &q);
    printf("%s and %d and %d", input, p, q);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem with above code: it will fail if user enters

mystring (OR)

mystring 100

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what problems you had with that attempt. You have used the `scanf` tag so I assume you tried to use that. Why were you unable to get that to work with `scanf`?

Comment: The main problem is that the number of integers following the string can vary

Comment: So just call `scanf` in a loop. Again, please show the code you have tried.

Comment: If the problem is only the unknown number of integers, then you should have a solution for only one integer. Please show your code for that, it will make it easy to help you extend it to one-or-two. As it is the question lacks focus on the actual problem and gives an impression of asking a general "please give the code".

Comment: @kaylum how do I know when to call scanf in loop the user has already hit the enter

Comment: @Yunnosch I am implementing stack program
The user will enter like
push 100,
pop
etc

Comment: That does not seem to be an answer to my comment. But if you want to add info, then please [edit] your question again.

Comment: However, if you have something like a command first and then one or two numbers, then I assume that after reading the command you should be able to predict how many numbers will follow. I.e. some commands have one parameter, others two; and as soon as you know the command in the current line you know whether to scan for one or two. On the other hand, scanf is the wrong tool for anything which might be invalid input. Consider reading complete lines, then check first for validity and then parse for semantics.

Comment: Here is my favorite link for any trouble with specifically scanf and generally input. If anything goes wrong I just read it again: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Yes I know for what string how many integers the user will enter,

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. Each `scanf` call can consume part or all of the entered input. For example, you can do `scanf("%s")` to read the first string. After that the input buffer will still contain the next integer(s). You can then call `scanf("%d")` in a loop until it returns 0 or until the expected number of integers has been read.

Comment: You are aware that scanf has a return value, aren't you? Your code (like most with problems around scanf) ignores it unwisely, but surely your read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf if not, see the other link I provided.

Comment: @kaylum I didn't know of the buffer, I know how to code it now thanks

Comment: @SoLo -- note that an `int` may not be able to hold a value of 10^9, but a `long int` will.

Comment: @exnihilo Ok I will take care of that, I am now using scanf to read the string(the user will enter string aswell as numbers in one line only), then I will send the read string through some checks to decide how many numbers i want.

Comment: @SoLo -- also, you should always specify maximum width when using `%s` to avoid potential buffer overflow and undefined behavior. `scanf()` and friends always write a terminating `\0` for the string, so with `char input[100]` you need `scanf("%99s", input)` to avoid writing past the end of `input[]` in the event of large user-input strings.

Comment: @exnihilo I know all the possible string commands that can be entered, they are not more than 20 length, so should I still worry of overflow?

Comment: @SoLo -- always assume that users are malicious where user-input is concerned ;) Better safe than sorry....

Comment: Are these valid inputs? `foo bar 14`, `February 9th, 2020`, `one 2 three 4 five 6 7`, `1000 1001 1002 1003`, `42`, `-42`

Answer (score 0):

My approach is as follows : 
 1.Take the whole this an input string i.e mystring 100 100 (or) mystring 100 (or) mystring
 2.Split the string by "white space" using **strtok** keyword
 3.Maintain a variable count,
if count is 1 and count is 2 typecast into a integer and 
   store it into their respective variables. 
`

```
// CODE
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char str[] = "mystring 130 102";
char *token = strtok(str, " "); 
char *mystring =token ; 

int count = 0 ;

while (token != NULL) 
{ 
    if(count == 1 )
      num1 = atoi(token);
    if(count == 2) 
      num2 = atoi(token) ; 
    token = strtok(NULL, " "); 
    count++ ;
} 
printf("%s\n" , mystring);
printf("%d\n" , num1) ; 
printf("%d\n" , num2) ; 

return 0;
```

*EDIT*
We can still use *sscanf()* to reduce the complexity as per comment below by

```
char *mystring = "mystring 102 293";
char str[20] ; 
int num1, num2[100];
strcpy( dtm, "mystring 102 293" );
sscanf( dtm, "%s  %d  %d", str, &num1, &num2 );
printf("%s\n" , mystring);
printf("%d\n" , num1) ; 
printf("%d\n" , num2) ;
```

Comment: Why use `strtok()` and `atoi()`, with the associated complexities and problems, when you could just use `sscanf()`?